# unused argument in train function

Tags: r, random-forest, hyperparameters

Good day to all

I have a problem in code when I use RF hyperparameter tuning. The algorithm (Simulated annealing) give me the RMSE value of 4000. I am not sure from where it has performed this calculation because in the code I did not specify any grid/values? The code is below, which was originally for SVM but I edited for RF.

```
svm_obj <- function(param, maximize = FALSE) {
  mod <- train(Effort ~ ., data = tr,
               method = "rf",
               preProc = c("center", "scale", "zv"),
               metric = "MAE",
               trControl = ctrl,
               tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 10^(param[1])))
               ##, sigma = 10^(param[2])))
  if(maximize)
    -getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainRMSE"] else
      getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainRMSE"]
}

## Simulated annealing from base R
set.seed(45642)
san_res <- optim(par = c(0), fn = svm_obj, method = "SANN",
                 control = list(maxit = 10))

The answer I get is: $value
[1] 4487.821

$counts
function gradient 
      10       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Hey, it works for me. What error did you get? your Mtry should be between 0 to 1.

Comment: I posted something like an answer below, let me know if you can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mtry is the number of variables used by rf to split the tree, and it cannot be more than the number of columns of predictors.

Let's do a model that doesn't work:

```
  mod <- train(Effort ~ ., data = tr,
               method = "rf",
               preProc = c("center", "scale", "zv"),
               metric = "RMSE",
               trControl = ctrl,
               tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = ncol(tr)+1)
               )
```

You see a warning:

```
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

And the results, and final model disagrees:

```
mod$results

 mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD     MAESD
1   12 2.203626 0.9159377 1.880211 0.979291  0.1025424 0.7854203

 mod$finalModel

Call:
 randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = param$mtry)
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 10

          Mean of squared residuals: 6.088637
                    % Var explained: 82.7
```

So although you specified mtry=12, the default randomForest function brings it down to 10, which is sensible. But if you try this over optim, you are never going to get something that makes sense, once you go over ncol(tr)-1.

If you do not have so much variables, it's much easier to use tuneLength or specify the mtry to use. Let's start with the results you expect with just specifying mtry:

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

ctrl = trainControl(method="cv",repeats=3)
#use mtcars
tr = mtcars
# set mpg to be Effort so your function works
colnames(tr)[1] = "Effort"

TG =  data.frame(mtry=1:10)
mod <- train(Effort ~ ., data = tr,
               method = "rf",
               preProc = c("center", "scale", "zv"),
               metric = "RMSE",
               trControl = ctrl,
               tuneGrid = TG)

mod$results
   mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
1     1 2.725944 0.8895202 2.384232 1.350958  0.1592133 1.183400
2     2 2.498627 0.9012830 2.192391 1.276950  0.1375281 1.200895
3     3 2.506250 0.8849148 2.168141 1.229709  0.1562686 1.173904
4     4 2.503700 0.8891134 2.170633 1.249049  0.1478276 1.168831
5     5 2.480846 0.8837597 2.148329 1.250889  0.1540574 1.191068
6     6 2.459317 0.8872104 2.126315 1.196187  0.1554423 1.128351
7     7 2.493736 0.8736399 2.165258 1.158384  0.1766644 1.082568
8     8 2.530672 0.8768546 2.199941 1.224193  0.1681286 1.127467
9     9 2.547422 0.8757422 2.196878 1.222921  0.1704655 1.130261
10   10 2.514791 0.8720315 2.184602 1.224944  0.1740556 1.093184
```

Maybe something like 6 is the best mtry you can get.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort. However, the problem arises when I use some optimization algorithm. I have edited the question, kindly if you could look at it. At this point, I am not sure how this algorithm (Simulated annealing) calculated the results because the mtry value is not initialized anywhere int he code. And it gives me the answer but I doubt this answer

Comment: @JavedKhan, optimizing the way you are doing now doesn't make sense. 1. the mtry has to be less than the number of predictors and it must be an integer. See above

Comment: I don't know about your data, but it's good to try the tuneLength or tuneGrid over a range of values, and think about whether they can actually converge, or give a false convergence, and lastly, whether convergence is at all meaningful.

Comment: Hi StupidWolf, my data (dependent variable is Effort) is a continuous data like 234.5, 453.0, 1111.26 etc. So according to your statement above, if I use tuneLength, I just specify a value i.e. 15 and if use tuneGrid, I need to use expand.grid and specify the list like expand.grid(mtry={1,3,5,7,9}. But in this case, I am not sure how can I use these information later in the optimization algorithm such as Simulated Annealing, which has the following code: san_res <- optim(par = c(0), fn = svm_obj, method = "SANN",
                 control = list(maxit = num_mods))

Comment: @JavedKhan, my point is, there is no much gained from doing optim on mtry. It really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know. Even I believe RF is not sensitive to parameter tuning as proved by some recent studies. But I need to use these optim for other algorithms also like extreme gradient boosting and neural networks. Maybe your tips help me there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont know what values are you calling your function with, so it's hard to spot the error.

However, mtry is a value that needs to be between 1 and the number of columns, while it looks to me like you might be setting it to 10 to the power of something - which is most likely out of bounds :)

Comment: @Divide DN, the code was originally for the parameters of SVM (C and Sigma), which I edited for RF. Do you think I should not use 10 to the power of something for the values of mtry?

Comment: That is correct. Mtry tells you how many variables your trees should use.
I dont know what package you're using - if it's R's randomforest than it sould be an integer between 1 and numcol(x), but other packages may use it in terms of ratio, so between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

@Javed @Wolf

Please mind that id DOES make sense to tune mtry.
mtry is going to affect the correlation between the trees you grow (therefore the variance of the model), and it is very problem specific, so the optimal value might change depending on the number of features you have and correlations between them.
It is however quite useless to tune bias-related hyperparameters (max depth, and other stopping/pruning rules). It takes a lot of time and the effects are often non significant.